# Multiline title on a JavaFx Chart

Tags: javafx

Is there some means - short of extending the JavaFX charting base class(es) - to specify a multi-line title string?

As seen in the screenshot the title is the only element 'wanting' more space.

[image]

I had seen some references to using a newline `'\n'` and even a pipe character `'|'` in the string but they apparently do not work for the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just threw this in a sample I had and it worked.

```
    chart.setTitle("really long title...........\n.............and some more ");
    Label l = (Label)chart.lookup(".chart-title");
    l.setWrapText(true);
```

The \n sets the break point if I don't want it at the limit.

As you can see it's just a Label, the hard part is getting it.

You can also use a css file with the selector.  I think it's already centered.

```
.chart-title{
    -fx-wrap-text : true;
    -fx-alignment : center;
}
```

Comment: Great! Both approaches are appreciated.